# Calculate the numbers of occurrences of items in a set using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I calculate the occurrences of items and all the combinations in an itemset using Pandas in Python. I tried using Apriori algorithm but the minimun value I can use for  minimum support is 0.1. Is there another way to do this?

```
frequent_itemsets = apriori(df_rules_nf, min_support=0.3, use_colnames=True)
frequent_itemsets['length'] = frequent_itemsets['itemsets'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
frequent_itemsets
```

My input dataframe looks like this:

```
df('Rules')= 
a|b|c
c
a
a|b
b|c
```

Output:

```
df_out=
Combos Occurrenecs
a        3/5
b        3/5
c        3/5
a,b      2/5
b,c      2/5
a,c      1/5
```

The above output represents the number of times the items are seen together or individually/ Total number of events. The occurrences can be in decimal format.

For eg: 'a' has been seen 3 times out of 5 events whereas a,b has been seen together 2 times out of 5 events.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `itertools.combinations` and a dictionary comprehension. But before you need to use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to split on the | to different columns.

```
# input 
s = pd.Series({0: 'a|b|c', 1: 'c', 2: 'a', 3: 'a|b', 4: 'b|c'})

# expand to dataframe
df_dum = s.str.get_dummies().astype(bool)
print(df_dum)
       a      b      c
0   True   True   True
1  False  False   True
2   True  False  False
3   True   True  False
4  False   True   True
```

then you do all for each combination of each length in the possibilities and use all along the columns

```
from itertools import combinations

d_ = {','.join(cols): # to get index as shown
      df_dum[list(cols)].all(axis=1).sum() # get the number of rows with 
                                      # all True in the col combination
      for i in range(1, df_dum.shape[1]+1) # different length of combination
      for cols in combinations(df_dum.columns, i)} # all different combinations length i

res = pd.Series(d_)
print(res)
a        3
b        3
c        3
a,b      2
a,c      1
b,c      2
a,b,c    1
dtype: int64
```

I would keep the result like this, but to fit your expected output, you can do

```
res = res.astype(str) + f'/{len(s)}'
print(res)
a        3/5
b        3/5
c        3/5
a,b      2/5
a,c      1/5
b,c      2/5
a,b,c    1/5
dtype: object
```

Note that this way is interesting if you don't have too many diffent values as input

Answer (score 0):

You could first turn your logical expressions into sets of variables:

```py
import pandas as pd

Rules = pd.DataFrame({'Source': ['a|b|c', 'c', 'a', 'a|b', 'b|c']})
Rules['Set'] = Rules.Source.str.split('|').apply(set)

Rules
```

```
    Source  Set
0   a|b|c   {b, c, a}
1   c       {c}
2   a       {a}
3   a|b     {b, a}
4   b|c     {b, c}
```

Now you can use the `powerset()` function from the `more_itertools` library to get all combinations (slicing with `[1:]` to exclude the empty set). Then, for each combination, count how many sets in the source dataframe it is a subset of:

```py
from more_itertools import powerset

union = set(x for s in Rules.Set for x in s)
combos = list(powerset(union))[1:]
occurrences = [sum(set(combo).issubset(s) for s in Rules.Set) for combo in combos]
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Combos': combos, 
                       'Occurrences': occurrences}) 

df_out
```

```
    Combos      Occurrences
0   (b,)        3
1   (c,)        3
2   (a,)        3
3   (b, c)      2
4   (b, a)      2
5   (c, a)      1
6   (b, c, a)   1
```